# GET request with parameters

Tags: swift, swift3, nsurlsession

Which way is recomed in swift 3 for GET with parameters ?

Example :

```
https://my-side.com/data?token=AS7F87SAD84889AD/
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `NSURLQueryItem`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Example how to use `URLQueryItem` for the requests.

```
func getRequest(params: [String:String]) {

    let urlComp = NSURLComponents(string: "https://my-side.com/data")!

    var items = [URLQueryItem]()

    for (key,value) in params {
        items.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
    }

    items = items.filter{!$0.name.isEmpty}

    if !items.isEmpty {
      urlComp.queryItems = items
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlComp.url!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    })
    task.resume()
}


getRequest(params: ["token": "AS7F87SAD84889AD"])
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, if `items` is empty (no params), it will add a "?" on the URL, which may lead to a 404. So do `urlComp.queryItems = items` only if `items` is not empty, no?

Comment: hi @OlegGordiichuk  on which page will I call the getRequest(params: ["token": "AS7F87SAD84889AD"])
?

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm handling my http requests like this:

```
func getData(completionHandler: @escaping ((result:Bool)) -> ()) {

        // Asynchronous Http call to your api url, using NSURLSession:
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://my-side.com/data?token=AS7F87SAD84889AD/") else {
            print("Url conversion issue.")
            return
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // Check if data was received successfully
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                do {
                    // Convert NSData to Dictionary where keys are of type String, and values are of any type
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]

                    //do your stuff

                    completionHandler(true)

                } catch {
                    completionHandler(false)
                }
            }
            else if error != nil
            {
                completionHandler(false)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: How you add params to the request?

Comment: the url contains the parameters.

Comment: it is a bit incorrect behavior because it is not flexible but just hardcoded

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk You are right, token will get changed after every entry. But it does not mean its not a way to do that - not best but some. Thx both of you for help!