# Swift Request Not working

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use this link https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/search?query=Taylor Force Act to query a bill.

In my iOS app , I'm trying to use a postString parameter ("query= "TaylorForcedAct") to get the results I would get if I entered the same URL on a web browser. Unfortunately, while using Swift , I get a 403 error:

```
status code: 403, headers { "Content-Length" = 551; "Content-Type" = "text"
```

While if I do so in a browser, it returns data successfully.

I can't access it by requesting using swift , only in the Address bars, why?]

Edit: Sorry for all the errors, I wrote this really late at night here is the swift code

```
func authentication3() {


let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/search?")!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")



//let poststring = "query= TaylorForceAct"
request.httpBody = "query=TaylorForceAct".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
//request.addValue("\"Taylor Force Act\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "query")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("error=\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        return
    }

    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

    print("Requestttt = \(String(describing: request.url?.absoluteURL))")

    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    print("responseString = \(responseString ?? "L")")
   }
task.resume()
   }
```

and the response:

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000038040> { URL: https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/search? } { status code: 403, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 551;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Sat, 10 Jun 2017 16:57:23 GMT";
    Server = CloudFront;
    Via = "1.1 b4b2849aaf2c14969531f9514611da28.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)";
    "x-amz-cf-id" = "vH379ZK57HN6pqgCQsdWD7x_jv5_xTzB5uMX3krdoSRR92pKFKWeag==";
    "x-cache" = "Error from cloudfront";
} })
Requestttt = Optional(https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/search?)
responseString = <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: vH379ZK57HN6pqgCQsdWD7x_jv5_xTzB5uMX3krdoSRR92pKFKWeag==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

And the browser's response using the same parameters and URL(https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/search?query=TaylorForceAct):

```
{"results":[],"count":0,"page":{"count":0,"per_page":20,"page":1}}
```

Solution: I was an idiot and trying to post with a GET... the correct solution would be like that the chosen answer is: using URLcomponets to parse together a url.

Comment: Show your code that you have tried with so far and it will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: You cannot use `httpBody` with a `GET` request. You have to append `?query=...` to the URL. You shouldn't set `Content-Type` either. A `GET` request has no content.

Comment: Sending this as `POST` results in 403 status code in the response. I'm surprised that your content length was 551. It would be interesting to see what the body was in this response (e.g. print `String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)`)

Comment: I'd remove the `Accept` being set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, because that's not what the response is. It's JSON.

Comment: Web Browsers do indeed GET by default. That's one point. For the second one, you don't put the parameter into HTTPBody in GET requests, it's in the URL. That's why it's still not working. You can use `(NS)URLQueryItems` (see there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696851/get-request-with-parameters), or if it's just for one parameter, do it yourself in the URL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular web service requires `GET` request. It sends you 403 status code if the request is a `POST` request.

I'd also suggest percent encoding the request (e.g. you can use `URLComponents` to do that for you). Thus:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/search")!
let item = URLQueryItem(name: "query", value: "\"Taylor Force Act\"")
components.queryItems = [item]
let request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to use a postString parameter

If I understand you correctly, you are using `POST` method.

That's incorrect. When you write a URL to browser, the `GET` method is used.

You will get a 403 (Forbidden) response with `POST`. This method is obviously not supported by the API for search (confirmed in REST client):

[image]

Comment: Question is edited for clarification, Thank you, so POST is a no go. Only GET would work. Any idea why https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/bills/search?query=Taylor works for browsers but not when I'm doing a url request in swift? Maybe my code is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

403 error code means forbidden access. In some services the reason for that is an absence of specified `User-Agent` http request header. You can try the following code:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36"])
```

And test your request again

Comment: User Agent is the less likely problem. Usually the problem is the absence of a session cookie or some missing header.

Comment: @Sulthan before answering I inspected the request in browser's developer console. There are no cookies and no http-headers except for standard Accept, Cache-Control and User-Agent.

Comment: Well, it's a public API so that would be surprising. The code is probably used incorrectly or it's hitting the transport security. User agent is very unlikely because API use them only for basic information about devices, not to block devices.

Comment: Well, you are right, my guess was stupid. Inspite of that there really was a tiny probability of missing header.

Comment: That's true. Browser APIs are usually lenient for missing headers. The real problem here is the missing code in OP which would make the error obvious.

Comment: @Sulthan I was facing as well this problem (error 403). It turned out that the `User-Agent` was the culprit. Since iOS 15, the default `User-Agent` is the `<AppName>/<AppVersion> CFNetwork/<CFNetworkVersion> Darwin/<DarwinVersion>`. Some servers don't like that and respond with error 403.