# How to send POST request with both parameter and body for JSON data in Swift 3 using Alamofire 4?

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

Postman api url added below.
[image]

Present code :

```
let baseUrl = "abc.com/search/"
let param  =  [
        "page":"1",
        "size":"5",
        "sortBy":"profile_locality"
    ]

    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]


    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request("\(baseUrl)field", method: .post,parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request ?? "no request")  // original URL request
        if(response.response?.statusCode != nil){
            print("done")
            if self.checkResponse(response.response!.statusCode){
                let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
                //print("at_LeadStop json \(json)")
                return completionHandler(json, false)

            } else {
                return completionHandler(JSON.null, true)
            }
        } else {
            print("gone")
            return completionHandler(JSON.null, true)
        }}
```

I don't know how to add body request through this code. Please help  me to slove this problem.

Comment: Don't you passing  `param` in `parameters` argument

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696851/get-request-with-parameters to construct the URL? and [{fieldName}] stuff in params

Comment: Thanks @NiravD for comment. I had pass parameters argument.

Comment: @KushalShrestha Then what else you want ?

Comment: How to pass body [ 
 {
 "fieldName" : "abc",
 "fieldValue":"xyz" 
 },
 {
 "fieldName" : "123",
 "fieldValue":"789" 
 }
]

Comment: In my comment I suggested to create the URL with `page`, `size`, etc, and the body params `fieldName`, put them into the `params` of the Alamofire method.

Comment: @Larme `Parameters` is define like this `public typealias Parameters = [String: Any]` So you cannot pass array with `parameters` argument

Comment: Oh that's true, that a Alamofire Limitation I still don't understand while AFNetworking accept both.

Comment: @Larme the better question is why `Alamofire` __doesn't__ accept both...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are mixing two things here, `page`,`size` and `sortBy` is you need to pass with the url string as query string. Now your body is request is `JSON` Array and you can post array with `Alamofire` only using `URLRequest`. So try like this.

```
let baseUrl = "abc.com/search/"
let queryStringParam  =  [
    "page":"1",
    "size":"5",
    "sortBy":"profile_locality"
]
//Make first url from this queryStringParam using URLComponents
var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: baseUrl)!
let queryItems = queryStringParam.map  { URLQueryItem(name: $0.key, value: $0.value) }
urlComponent.queryItems = queryItems

//Now make `URLRequest` and set body and headers with it
let param = [
    [
        "fieldName" : "abc",
        "fieldValue":"xyz"
    ],
    [
        "fieldName" : "123",
        "fieldValue":"789"
    ]
]
let headers = [ "Content-Type": "application/json" ]
var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponent.url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

//Now use this URLRequest with Alamofire to make request
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
    //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Using **Custom Encoding**

```
 struct JSONStringArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let array: [[String : Any]]

    init(array: [[String : Any]]) {
        self.array = array
    }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])

        if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

**Calling**

```
let values  = [
            [
                "fieldName" : "abc",
                "fieldValue":"xyz"
            ],
            [
                "fieldName" : "123",
                "fieldValue":"789"
            ]
        ]

        let param  =  [
            "page":"1",
            "size":"5",
            "sortBy":"profile_locality"
        ]

        let parameterEncoding = JSONStringArrayEncoding.init(array: values)

        Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding:parameterEncoding  ).validate().response { (responseObject) in
            // do your work
        }
```