# Convert dictionary to query string in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary as `[String:Any]`.Now i want to convert this dictionary keys & value as `key=value&key=value`.I have created below extension to work but it didn't work for me.

```
extension Dictionary {

    var queryString: String? {
        var output: String = ""
        for (key,value) in self {
            output +=  "\(key)=\(value)\(&)"
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Comment: The Foundation framework provides the classes  `URLComponents / URLQueryItems` for this purpose. And why is `queryString` optional?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824746/6433023 to Make Array of `URLQueryItems` from `Dictionary`

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838558/4061501

Comment: @rmaddy all answers here crash when you pass nested dictionary.

Comment: @SuhasAithal Why are you telling me? It's not my question. None of the answers are mine. If you have a different need then post your own question with all relevant details. Even link to this question as a similar, but different need.

Comment: With your points I thought you will be able to do something about this. I mean, copy pasting solution from here is more dangerous for the apps coz it will work in most of the simple cases where dictionary values are string and might lead to crash in production app where dictionary is nested or values are of some other object type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var populatedDictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]

extension Dictionary {
    var queryString: String {
        var output: String = ""
        for (key,value) in self {
            output +=  "\(key)=\(value)&"
        }
        output = String(output.characters.dropLast())
        return output
    }
}

print(populatedDictionary.queryString)

// Output : key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: why not increasing index

Comment: index plays no role here. I just dropped last char from the string. I have updated output I got. Is that what u required??

Comment: why downvote. Ans satisfied the requirement. I know there are many ways to accomplish same task, Instead of implementing same task another way ,I just modified @deepakkumar existing code to match the requirements.

Comment: @luckyShubhra have you tried to run the code it has one error in it `Use of unresolved identifier 'output'`, that's why someone down-voted it, please correct it otherwise other user will also down-vote it.

Comment: @VarunNaharia thanx for pointing it out. I forget to declare output var. I have edited the ans. Have a look.

Comment: if you use a value with the spaces or "?" or "&" you won't get an URL with this query string

Comment: @luckyShubhra, does this work when there are nested dictionaries? That might be why it was downvoted.

Comment: @luckyShubhra What if dictionary is nested??

Answer (score 28):

Use [NSURLQueryItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlqueryitem).

> An NSURLQueryItem object represents a single name/value pair for an
>   item in the query portion of a URL. You use query items with the
>   queryItems property of an NSURLComponents object.

To create one use the designated initializer `queryItemWithName:value:` and then add them to `NSURLComponents` to generate an `NSURL`. For example:

**OBJECTIVE-C:**

```
NSDictionary *queryDictionary = @{ @"q": @"ios", @"count": @"10" };
NSMutableArray *queryItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in queryDictionary) {
    [queryItems addObject:[NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:key value:queryDictionary[key]]];
}
components.queryItems = queryItems;
NSURL *url = components.URL; // http://stackoverflow.com?q=ios&count=10
```

**Swift:**

```
let queryDictionary = [ "q": "ios", "count": "10" ]
var components = URLComponents()
components.queryItems = queryDictionary.map {
     URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)
}
let URL = components.url
```

Comment: Please write code in Swift because question tagged with Swift

Comment: Thats good But now instead of using `absoluteString` use directly url

Comment: This crashes when you pass nested dictionary

Comment: @SuhasAithal you can not pass nested dict as a URL encoded format. Try to convert  that nested dict to string before encoding.

Answer (score 27):

Another Swift-esque approach:

```
let params = [
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Test"
]

let urlParams = params.flatMap({ (key, value) -> String in
    return "\(key)=\(value)"
}).joined(separator: "&")
```

Comment: Thank you it working greate in Swift 4.2
But now ```.flatMap``` become ```.compactMap``` in Swift 4.2

Comment: You're forgetting to encode the values

Answer (score 5):

```
extension Dictionary {
    var queryString: String? {
        return self.reduce("") { "\($0!)\($1.0)=\($1.1)&" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, but leaves last "&"

Comment: That can be remedied easily, I've used:

`return self.isEmpty ? "" : String(self.reduce("") {"\($0)\($1.0)=\($1.1)&"` and dropped the optional of the var. Use it like 
`"...some-path?\(params.queryString)"` . Also make sure to properly encode and sanitize your dictionary. This stuff can break

Answer (score 3):

Same as @KKRocks with update for swift 4.1.2

```
func queryItems(dictionary: [String:Any]) -> String {
    var components = URLComponents()
    print(components.url!)
    components.queryItems = dictionary.map {
        URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: String(describing: $1))
    }
   return (components.url?.absoluteString)!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Compact version of @luckyShubhra's answer

**Swift 5.0**

```
extension Dictionary {
    var queryString: String {
        var output: String = ""
        forEach({ output += "\($0.key)=\($0.value)&" })
        output = String(output.dropLast())
        return output
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let populatedDictionary = ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]
let urlQuery = populatedDictionary.queryString
print(urlQuery)
```

Comment: I think StringProtocol conformance will make this safer. ie extension Dictionary where Key : StringProtocol, Value : StringProtocol ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
func queryItems(dictionary: [String:Any]) -> String {
        var components = URLComponents()
        print(components.url!)
        components.queryItems = dictionary.map {
            URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)
        }
       return (components.url?.absoluteString)!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

    extension URL {
        var queryItemsDictionary: [String: String] {
            var queryItemsDictionary = [String: String]()

            // we replace the "+" to space and then encode space to "%20" otherwise after creating URLComponents object
            // it's not possible to distinguish the real percent from the space in the original URL
            let plusEncodedString = self.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%20")

            if let queryItems = URLComponents(string: plusEncodedString)?.queryItems {
                queryItems.forEach { queryItemsDictionary[$0.name] = $0.value }
            }
            return queryItemsDictionary
        }
    }
```

That extension will allow you to parse URL where you have both encoded + sign and space with plus, for example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/?q=First+question&email=mail%2B10@mail.com
```

That extension will parse "q" as "First question" and "email" as "mail+10@mail.com"

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol ParametersConvertible {
    func asParameters() -> [String:Any] 
}

protocol QueryStringConvertible {
    func asQuery() -> String
}

extension QueryStringConvertible where Self: ParametersConvertible {
    func asQuery() -> String {
        var queries: [URLQueryItem] = []
        for (key, value) in self.asParameters() {
            queries.append(.init(name: key, value: "\(value)"))
        }

        guard var components = URLComponents(string: "") else {
            return ""
        }

        components.queryItems = queries
        return components.percentEncodedQuery ?? ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this function to your controller**

```
func getQueryString(params : [String : Any])-> String{

        let urlParams = params.compactMap({ (key, value) -> String in
            return "\(key)=\(value)"
        }).joined(separator: "&")
        var urlString = "?" + urlParams
        if let url = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed){
            urlString = url
        }
          return urlString
    }
```

**Example**

**self.getQueryString(params: ["name" : "deep ios developer" , "age" :22])**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants the "short, short" version.

Condensed using map, you don't need the forEach or for loops. Also protocol constrained for type enforcement on the dictionary.

```
extension Dictionary where Key : StringProtocol, Value : StringProtocol {
    var queryString: String {
        self.map { "\($0)=\($1)" }.joined(separator: "&")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this helper fn, which I thought was clean:

```
private static func queryStringParamsToString(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) -> String {
    return dictionary
        .map({(key, value) in "\(key)=\(value)"})
        .joined(separator: "&")
        .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!

}
```