# URLQueryItem value is optional

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

Hello I am trying to add queryItems to my URLComponents but because URLQueryItem returns its value as an optional the url keeps having a question mark in it.

```
var params = ["id":"5"]
let queryParams = toStringDictionary(dictionary: params).map { pair in
    return URLQueryItem(name: pair.key, value: pair.value)
}
var components = URLComponents(string: fullURL)
components.queryItems = queryParams
print(components.url)//This is the full url https://demo.com/users/?5
                     //This https://demo.com/users/?5 should be this https://demo.com/users/5
```

The question mark is of course resulting in a wrong url. I can't get rid of it.

Comment: What is the `fullURL`?

Comment: What does toStringDictionary do?

Comment: i think the sign '?' in https://demo.com/users/?5 not mean that item is optional, it's just mean start of parameters in url

Comment: you need just remove last '/' from fullURL

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44838558/4061501

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert dictionary to query string in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838500/convert-dictionary-to-query-string-in-swift)

Comment: __there is no optional here__, you just don't understand the difference between the ULR's _path_ and the URL's _query-string_; the query string is always after `?` in the URL while the path is always _before_ the `?`... hardcore stuff to pick up the basics: [RFC-3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), educational.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Query parameters are separated from the rest of the url by a question mark, for example:

```
https://example.com/path?param_name=param_value
```

The question mark is not due to an optional, but is the way that query params are supplied.

The example in your comment looks like it has lost the name of the param, I would expect it to read

```
https://demo.com/users/?id=5
```

If it definitely doesn't include the `id=` bit, please could you share the implementation of `toStringDictionary` so that we can see what's going on there? The dictionary you pass in is already a string dictionary, so seems odd to have such a function.

**EDIT: following your clarifications** (which have now disappeared, but made it clear that you were looking to add to the path rather than the query string)

It looks like your code is adding query parameters correctly; look closer at the URL it produces, it will be `https://demo.com/users/?id=5`. Query parameters are not part of the path, they come at the end and are separated from the rest of the URL by a ?

From your edits, it looks as though what you actually want to do is to add to the path of the URL, so that you get `https://demo.com/users/5`. That URL does not have any query parameters, so `URLQueryItem` is the wrong tool for the job.

To add to the path, you can do something like the following:

```
let userID = "5"
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/users")!
let newUrl = url.appendingPathComponent(userID)
print(newUrl.absoluteString) //https://example.com/users/5
```

NB - `url` is only force unwrapped for brevity in the example, since the string passed to URL() is known to be valid. In real use, you should treat the optional more carefully.

Comment: It was me failing to understand what the function was doing. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your `toStringDictionary`

Assuming

```
let fullURL = "https://demo.com/users/"
```

all you need to do is…

```
let queryParams = params.map{ URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1) }

var components = URLComponents(string: fullURL)!
components.queryItems = queryParams
print(components.url!)

// https://demo.com/users/?id=5
```

Note that you should avoid the force unwrapping in practice