# How do I send POST Request with body in my Code Below

Tags: swift, post, alamofire

[image]

I need to do a POST request using JSON,
I referred to this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44824746/9704569)

And below is the Code what I Tried.

```
let markURL = urls.studentListMark
let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization":"token" + " " + ProfileAuth]
let params = [
    "course":1,
    "batch":1
]
var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: markURL)!
let queryItems = params.map  { URLQueryItem(name: $0.key, value: $0.value as? String) }
print("queryItems ==   \(queryItems)")
urlComponent.queryItems = queryItems

let url  = URL(string: markURL)

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

  Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
    //Your code
    if((response.result.value) != nil) {
        var jsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print("&&&&&&&&&")
        print(jsonVar)
    }
}
```

When I execute this method, There is No response.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the request what is printed in log `print("queryItems ==  \(queryItems)")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Alamofire` with `parameters` field like this:

```
let params = [
    "course": 1,
    "batch": 1
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://YOURURL", parameters: params, encoding: .jsonEncoding).responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
    print(request)
    print(response)
    print(JSON)
    print(error)
}
```

I hope it is works.

Enjoy.

Comment: I tried this before, with params but Still No Response