# post request sending in it parameter of type [String: Any] and a body of type string

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

im creating a post request using alamofire library, I want to send a parameter which is:

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["customer_id":customerId!,"customer_new":"0","x-session":getXSession()]
```

and a body which is  of type string, the body:

```
fbackAnswers string = [{"type_id":"17","value":"4"},{"type_id":"12","value":"TEST"},{"type_id":"14","value":"3"},{"type_id":"19","value":"4"},{"type_id":"16","value":"3"},{"type_id":"13","value":"3"},{"type_id":"18","value":"3"},{"type_id":"15","value":"3"},{"type_id":"2","value":"4"},{"type_id":"11","value":"1"},{"type_id":"1","value":"2"},{"type_id":"8","value":"4"},{"type_id":"6","value":"2"},{"type_id":"4","value":"22-09-2017 - 15:12"},{"type_id":"5","value":"Test"}]
```

I made this request below:

```
 static func sendFeedbackResultOldCustomer(customerId: String?,fbackAnswers:String? , completion: @escaping (Bool , String?) ->() ){
            let fbackAns:String! = fbackAnswers!
            let parameters: Parameters = ["customer_id":customerId!,"customer_new":"0","x-session":getXSession()]

            Alamofire.request(APIStrings.feedbackSent, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: fbackAns, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in


                if (success){
                    completion(true, nil)
                }
                else {
                    completion(false, response?.result.error as? String)
                }
            }
```

its giving me an error : extra argument in call,
please correct it for me if this is not the way to send these types of requests, and if it is, please help me finding the error.
thanks

Comment: You are sending wrong param:  `encoding: fbackAns` it will be `encoding: URLEncoding.default`

Comment: And where are supposed to be "parameters"? Usually params are in body. Are yours supposed to be in the URLs?

Comment: yes , one parameter in the url, and the body, should not be in the parameter.  so where should I send the body?

Comment: Create yourself the URLRequest. Add the parameters in the URL with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696851/get-request-with-parameters use a Dictionary instead of a String for the `fbackAns`, and pass it as parameters (that should be transformed into JSON and added to the Body).   Use that request with Alamofire (instead of using String URL, use the method with URLRequest parameter). You can also use this https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manual-parameter-encoding-of-a-urlrequest for the params in the URL.

Comment: could you show an example how to transfer the fbackAns to json and added to the body?

Comment: Use `JSONSerialization` to transform `(NS)Dictionary`/`(NS)Array` to `(NS)Data`, so `myRequest.body = try? JSONSerialization(object:myArrayParamOfFeedbackAnswers, options:[])` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

It seems the `parameter` is a header and the `fbackAns` is a parameter.

```
static func sendFeedbackResultOldCustomer(customerId: String?,fbackAnswers:String? , completion: @escaping (Bool , String?) ->() ){
            let fbackAns:String! = fbackAnswers!
            let parameters: Parameters = ["customer_id":customerId!,"customer_new":"0","x-session":getXSession()]

            Alamofire.request(APIStrings.feedbackSent, method: HTTPMethod.post, parameters: fbackAns, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in


                if (success){
                    completion(true, nil)
                }
                else {
                    completion(false, response?.result.error as? String)
                }
            }
```

Comment: does the Parameter contains the body in post request?

Comment: Yes, this is a body! here we call it params